# Unable to call smart contract functions via web3.js in frontend Javascript

Tags: javascript, web3js, ganache

I am using frontend Javascript instead of Node to interact with a deployed contract on Ganache. The NodeJS version works perfectly but not the frontend JS version. It is unable to call all functions. Below is the code:

```
<script src="/node_modules/web3/dist/web3.min.js"></script>

<script>
        walletAddress = null;
        //Connecting to Blockchain
        var web3 = new Web3(Web3.givenProvider || "HTTP://127.0.0.1:7545");
        var contactAddress = '0xB16bEc01bfe4F13D5e85A2F75F51893D797Df1F7'
        var abi = '[{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"getValue","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"_value","type":"uint256"}],"name":"setValue","outputs":[],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"getMsgSender","outputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"","type":"address"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"}]'
        const abiJson = JSON.parse(abi);

        let init = async () => {
            ac = await web3.eth.getAccounts()
            walletAddress = ac[0]
            const contract = new web3.eth.Contract(
                abiJson,
                contactAddress
            );
            console.log(await contract.methods.setValue(900).send({from:walletAddress}));
            
            contract.methods.getValue().call().then(function (result) {
                console.log(result);
            });

        }
        init()
    </script>
```

None of the functions is being called. I do not know how to figure out whether it is actually interacting with Ganache or not.

Comment: Is the `Web3.givenProvider` set? Depending on the rest of your code and extensions installed in your browser (for example MetaMask), it might be set to a value different from the fallback option (the `:7545` local provider), which would cause the code trying to communicate with a provider on a different network, that doesn't have a contract deployed on the `0xB16bE...` address.

Comment: @PetrHejda the issue was `giveProivder` which was being `true` rather than the next condition.

Comment: I am also facing the same issue. Was your issue resolved?